# ssh shared key authentication asks for password, unless sshd runs with -d option

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, authentication

My client is Ubuntu, and the server is CentOS.  I have shared key authentication set up to login from client to server.
When I run the server like:

```
sudo `which sshd` -d
```

Everything works as expected; I don't get a user login prompt.  I take this to mean that everything is in the correct place, with correct permissions, etc.  When I restart the server in "normal" mode:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

My client prompts me for the user password.

Here is verbose output from success (sshd -d):

```
anregen@ba-vm-atf-01:~/workspace$ ssh -v web@test.lab.network.com
OpenSSH_6.0p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.1.1-814) (CentrifyDC build 5.1.1-814), OpenSSL 0.9.8w 23 Apr 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test.lab.network.com [172.20.80.45] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 1e:57:9c:69:d2:09:29:0b:5b:4d:e4:f7:98:ee:f5:94
debug1: Host 'test.lab.network.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to test.lab.network.com ([172.20.80.45]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Tue Jun 17 16:03:39 2014 from ba-vm-atf-01.lab.network.com
Environment:
  USER=web
  LOGNAME=web
  HOME=/var/www
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
  MAIL=/var/mail/web
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=172.20.80.27 32973 22
  SSH_CONNECTION=172.20.80.27 32973 172.20.80.45 22
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
  TERM=xterm
  SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
  SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
  SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
-bash-4.1$
```

And here is the verbose output from a "failure" `sudo service sshd restart`:

```
anregen@ba-vm-atf-01:~/workspace$ ssh -v web@test.lab.network.com
OpenSSH_6.0p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.1.1-814) (CentrifyDC build 5.1.1-814), OpenSSL 0.9.8w 23 Apr 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test.lab.network.com [172.20.80.45] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 1e:57:9c:69:d2:09:29:0b:5b:4d:e4:f7:98:ee:f5:94
debug1: Host 'test.lab.network.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MyNetwork.local/anregen/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
web@test.lab.network.com's password:
```

Any thoughts on what is going on with `-d` that makes this work?  Or is it something with running sshd outside of the `service` tool?

EDIT:  By request, here are server-side logs with `-d` option.  I added `#comments` to show the remote/client activity.

```
[anregen@ba-vm-web-01 ~]$ clear
[anregen@ba-vm-web-01 ~]$ sudo service sshd stop
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[anregen@ba-vm-web-01 ~]$ sudo `which sshd` -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.

# At this point, I log in from remote as "web"
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 172.20.80.27 port 37828
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user web service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "web"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "ba-vm-atf-01.lab.network.com"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user web service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: 6b:b4:a1:41:e2:7c:0a:c6:2b:6d:27:87:f4:3c:6e:0c
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for web from 172.20.80.27 port 37828 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user web service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: 6b:b4:a1:41:e2:7c:0a:c6:2b:6d:27:87:f4:3c:6e:0c
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for web from 172.20.80.27 port 37828 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: web has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support enabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
User child is on pid 19221
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 500/500
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.

# at this point I send "exit" from remote to logout
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 19222
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 19222
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
debug1: session_by_tty: session 0 tty /dev/pts/1
debug1: session_pty_cleanup: session 0 release /dev/pts/1
Received disconnect from 172.20.80.27: 11: disconnected by user
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: PAM: closing session
debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

Comment: What was logged on the server?

Comment: Do you have encrypted home directories?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance here: I do not have any sort of .encryptfs files or similar in my home directories.  Is that conclusive that the dirs are not encrypted?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm afraid I'm not ubuntu expert.  But encrypted home directories would produce exactly the result you're seeing, assuming that the `sudo sshd -d` was started by the same user that you were trying to ssh in as.

Comment: it isn't the same user.  On the client machine: "anregen", on the server machine: "web".  The user that `sudo` on the server is also anregen.  I have not set up any shared key association between the two anregen accounts though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton server logs added to the question

Comment: That's not helpful. It doesn't show the _failure_. Get the logs from your failed login.

Comment: could you help me find the log when I'm running without `-d`?  My understanding was that `-d` caused this log to be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; SELinux

I went back to using the same user account on both machines.  More importantly, this means I am using home directories that SELinux is on-board with.  You can see in the logs that the "web" user has non-standard home directory `/var/www/` (it is intended to be the web content mgmt account)

I then removed the `~/.ssh/` directory on the server machine, the went back over to the client and used `ssh-copy-id`.  That apparently recreated the `~/.ssh/` directory and auth files in a SELinux-compatible way.  Note that simply removing and recreating the .ssh directory for the "web" user was not sufficient.  It seems that when I changed the "web" user home directory, SELinux was not properly involved...

<strike>I don't have an answer as to why `-d` changes this behavior on the server-side,</strike> but if anyone else bumps into this, try removing the `~.ssh/` directory, and letting the `ssh-copy-id` script do the work for you.

*update* Apparently, because running it as `sudo` changes the security permissions for the process. So, even though a `ps` looks the same, I found that `ps -Z` (which is the SELinux-context-aware argument) does not.

<strike>The only thing left at this point is for me to research how to make a user with home directory `/var/www` in the SELinux-approved way so that it respects that accounts `authorized_keys` file</strike>

*update* I used `chcon -R --reference=/home/anregen/.ssh /var/www/.ssh`.  That was the trick that got the correct security context into the relocated "home" directory for user: web.  Keep in mind this is sort of temporary, meaning you should not just use chcon, but rather make a new policy.